# Issue implementing CORS in .net MVC 5

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, cors

I have a WebAPI project that is being deployed to `http://localhost:81/` on my local machine IIS, and a web project running from `http://localhost/` on the same machine.

The API calls from the web project, are being made using Angular.
Initially I got errors to add support for CORS which I solved by adding the following snippet to web.config in the WebAPI project:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE" />
      </customHeaders>  
</httpProtocol>
```

When I check my response headers in the browser console, I can confirm that CORS is now enabled. But the API call gets a 403 (Forbidden) error.

> GET `http://localhost:81/api/Sample/GetSomeNumber/1` 403 (Forbidden)

The method is not decorated with any attribute for authentication or authorization, it simply returns the parameter it received.

What am I missing here?

Comment: could iis be rejecting you?

Comment: Is there any way I could find out for sure?

Comment: you can look at the raw response from fiddler

Answer (score 1):

I followed your instructions and created two ASP.NET apps:

1. Web API project pointing to Local IIS, port 81.
2. MVC project point to Local IIS, (default) port 80.

After setting up the Web API project with CORS I too got a 403: Forbidden error when my app tried to access it. I also confirmed I got the error when I accessed it directly.

I found my problem was when I created my Web Site for my Web API on localhost:81, the Application Pool that was created for it defaulted to v2.0 instead of v4.0. I changed the application pool version, rebuilt my solution with the two projects, and then everything worked as expected.

**To change Application Pool Version**

1. Open IIS manager.
2. Double-click Application Pools.
3. Double-click the pool your localhost:81 app is associated with.
4. .NET Frawework version: .NET Framework v4.0.xxxxx (mine is 30319)
5. OK Button
6. Rebuild solution from Visual Studio